# Send File in POST Request with Windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have create an "csv file" in my windows phone, 
I want to post it, in a server, in the web and I don't find how I want to proceed for that,

I don't want just make a "post request" with parameters, I want to post my File in the server...

Actually, I'm connect to this server, but it don't find my file...

```
public void SentPostReport()
    {


        //Post response.
        string url = this.CurentReportkPI.configXml.gw; // string url 
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Accept = "application/CSV";
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), request);
    }

    private void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);

        // I create My csv File 
        CreateCsv reportCsv = new CreateCsv();
        string pathReportFile = reportCsv.CreateNewReport(this.report);
        string CsvContent = reportCsv.ReadFile(pathReportFile);

        // Convert the string into a byte array.
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(CsvContent);

        // Write to the request stream.
        postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        postStream.Close();

        // Start the asynchronous operation to get the response
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);
    }


    private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("GetResponseCallback");
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        string responseString = streamRead.ReadLine();
        // Close the stream object
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamRead.Close();

        // Release the HttpWebResponse
        response.Close();
    }
```

Have you an idea when I proceed for resolve my problem,and send my CSV File with my request ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem here, but on a POST request, you are supposed to set the ContentLength and ContentType ("application/x-www-form-urlencoded") headers, amongst other things...

Please check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) "how-to" article on a fully correct POST request -- It's not for Windows Phone, but I think you'll still get the full ideia!

On the other hand, I'd suggest you just go with [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) that will solve all these problems for you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily using RestSharp or Hammock with the AddFile method. Here's an example of what i did for uploading a photo using Hammock:

```
var request = new RestRequest("photo", WebMethod.Post);
request.AddParameter("photo_album_id", _album.album_id);
request.AddFile("photo", filename, e.ChosenPhoto);
request.Client.BeginRequest(request, (restRequest, restResponse, userState) =>
    { 
        // handle response 
    }
```

Comment: thank for your RestRequest Example, but, how I create and post a file just with an url for server address, and Filename and url for file to send?